# sending and receiving the selected spinner information from one activity to another activity

Tags: java, android

I have 10 spinners and one button. By clicking button  activity A is going to another activity B and I want to add the selected information from spinners to send from activity A to activity B by clicking that button and want to display selected spinners info in activity B.

Here is my code (activity A) :

```
public class Firstactivity extends MainActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private Spinner spin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third_layout_main);

        btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1s);
        spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final String arr[] = {"NONE"," 1*£5.49","2*2.00","3*4.00"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Firstactivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arr);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(Firstactivity.this, "the item selected "+arr[arg2],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                 //TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent inte = new Intent (Firstactivity.this, Finalorder.class);
                String Text = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
                startActivity(inte);

            }
        });
}}
```

Activity B :

```
public class Finalorder extends MainActivity {

    Bundle Bundle;
    TextView txt;
    Button btn;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.last);

        Bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1s);


        Bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        txt.setText(Bundle.getString("SPINNERVAL"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your custom serializable or parcelable object with all spinners values. And transfer it through activity.

Something like that:

```
public class SpinnersData implements Serializable
{
    private String spinner1;
    private String spinner2;
    //....
    private String spinner10;


    public String getSpinner1()
    {
        return spinner1;
    }
    public void setSpinner1(String spinner1)
    {
        this.spinner1 = spinner1;
    }
    public String getSpinner2()
    {
        return spinner2;
    }
    public void setSpinner2(String spinner2)
    {
        this.spinner2 = spinner2;
    }
    public String getSpinner10()
    {
        return spinner10;
    }
    public void setSpinner10(String spinner10)
    {
        this.spinner10 = spinner10;
    }
}
```

Put it to intent in one activity:

```
SpinnersData data = new SpinnersData();
data.setSpinner1(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
data.setSpinner2(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
....
yourIntent.putExtra("someKey", data);
```

And get in another activity in `onCreate()`:

```
SpinnersData data = (SpinnersData) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("someKey");
```

Now you can use this object to display information here.

Comment: still it is not displaying. displaying empty layout. not getting the selected spinners data.

Comment: can you post part of code where you put serializable object to intent and where you get it in another activity?

Comment: and are you sure that data present in every spinner? maybe this "spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString()" return empty string?

Comment: i tried from blue stacks app player. its is not opening. i don't know what the error in this code. here is the code                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619230/passing-spinner-information-to-another-activity#